# SequenceFile alternative/extension that allows in-place updates

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I like the convenience of a database where you can update a row **in-place**. But Hadoop relies on sequence files that are capable of being consumed in parallel.

I liked the idea of HBase where I can rewrite just one row; as well as being input to a map-reduce job. But HBase is not something a newb must mess with, right? What is a good tool/method for this?

Comment: The design of HDFS does not support to update in-place. That's why we need HBase

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's very difficult to learn and use HBase.

Coming to your original question. The reason why we use HBase is same as the reason behind using any other DB, i.e `random, real-time read/write access`, which HDFS lacks like any other FS. And this is true for any filesystem, not just for HDFS. You could take ext4 & MySQL paradigm as an example.

And when you say re-write in HBase it is actually not update. You either put a `new version` of a cell or `delete` a cell and `put` new data at the same location.

And you can't say that Hadoop relies on sequence files to provide you the parallelism. Parallelism is something which is provided by Hadoop by virtue of its nature, i'e a `distributed platform`. You can handle almost any kind of file using Hadoop with almost euqal parallelism. The only advantage with sequence files is that they are more suitable for `MapReduce processing` as they are already in `key/vale pairs`.

You have to take it with a pinch of salt, but frankly speaking Hadoop doesn't understand update. If you could elaborate your use case a bit more, maybe I could suggest something better.